# html5 video tag m3u8 file not working

Tags: html, ffmpeg, video-streaming

Step 1. ffmpeg work : .mp4 -> .m3u8 and .tp Files create

ffmpeg options :

> ffmpeg -y -i Internet.mp4 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec libx264 -acodec ac3 -r 30 -profile:v baseline -b:v 1500k -maxrate 2000k -s 480x300 -map 0 -flags -global_header -f segment -segment_list index_1500.m3u8 -segment_time 10 -segment_format mpeg_ts -segment_list_type m3u8 segment%05d.ts

Like this

Step 2. HTML5 programing

```
< !DOCTYPE html>

< html>

< head>

< title > Storage.html < /title >

< /head >

< body >

< video width="352" height="198" src="index_1500.m3u8"/>

< /body>

< /html>
```

html file create

but video play not working...

but, vlc media player [index_1500.m3u8] file play very well

Please Help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

m3u8 can only be played on safari in OSX/iOS using the video tag. For other browsers you must use a player such as jwplayer that uses flash.